# Exponential Growth Problem. Is this solution correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, exponential-function

I would just like to confirm that I'm doing this correctly. If not, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**The problem:**

A painting sold for $\$274$ in $1977$ and was sold again in $1987$ for $\$470$. Assume that the growth in the value $V$ of the collector’s item was exponential.

Find the value $k$ of the exponential growth rate. Assume $V_0 = 274$.

**My attempt at solving it:**

$470=274e^{10k}$

$k = 0.054$ (rounded to the nearest thousandth)

Comment: The answer is correct.

Comment: Correct, but you might want to write the exponent as $10k$.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. The exact value would be

$$k = \frac{1}{10}\ln{\left(\frac{470}{274}\right)}$$

which approximates to: $k \approx 0.054$ as you said. Well done.